# Getting Undefined

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am working on LoopBack and Angular project.
I have JSON object but I getting output null when accessing the JSON object.

I storing the object like this var file =   res.result.files.file;
where res has the JSON object
And Accessing the Object like this
var filename = file.name;
which is returning Undefined,

how can I get the name form the JSON Object
here is the output of the file

```
[{ container: 'Images',
    name: '1559211341196.jpg',
    type: 'multipart/form-data',
    field: 'file',
    size: 3577522,
    providerResponse: undefined }]
```

form this i want to access the 'name:' Parameter, I tried this file. name, but I am getting an output as null,

how can I access the name parameter and store it in a variable?

Here is the code:

```
{
    'use strict';
    module.exports = function (Picture) {
        Picture.afterRemote('upload', function (ctx, res, next) {
            var http = require('request');
            var file = res.result.files.file;
            console.log(file);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(file.container + file.name + file.size));
            var i = http.get('http://192.168.1.11:3000/api/Pictures/Images/files/1559211341196.jpg', { json: true }, (body) => {
            });
            console.log(i.uri.href);
            next();
        })
    };
}
```

Comment: thank you for the edit @Jelly Fish

Comment: Wellcome, also need to change the title as per question body, please change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response looks like an array of objects, so you will have to get it like this:

`var file = res.result.files.file[0];` or `res.result.files[0]`, it depends...

Maybe you could have several files, not just one? in that case i'd recomend to map them instead, something like...

`var files = res.result.files.reduce((l, i) => ({...l, [i.name]: i}),{})`

So you can have a map of files and access them with `files.file1, files['187263871623.jpg']` etc

EDIT1: I'd move that require('http') out od the export, it's a module, you can share it between calls and if you have it inside the export it'll probably be called more than once.